# Titanium Android App Crashes on Device

Tags: titanium, maps

I am making an app that uses google api for providing routes between two locations . My app is crashing regularly on android simulator and device as well. 
The code and error log is as :

**code**

```
var map=require('ti.map');
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({title:'win'});
Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e){
    //     ********FOR DEVICE*********
    // var clat=e.coords.latitude;
    // var clon=e.coords.longitude;

    var Map=map.createView({
        region:{
            /****For Simulator*****/
            latitude:28.5015171, 
            longitude:77.0857142,
            /*****For Device******/
            //  latitude:clat,  
            //  longitude:clon
        },
        title:Map,
        mapType : map.STANDARD_TYPE,
        animate : true,
        zoom:-10,
        regionFit : true,
        userLocation : true 
    });
    var Ann=[map.createAnnotation({ 
        /****For Simulator*****/
        latitude:28.5015171, 
        longitude:77.0857142,
        /*****For Device*****/
        // latitude:clat,  
        // longitude:clon
        title:"I m Here",
        subtitle:'My Current Location',
        pincolor:map.ANNOTATION_RED,
    }),
    map.createAnnotation({
        latitude:28.5686,
        longitude:77.1122,
        title:"Destination",
        subtitle:"I wish to be there",
        pincolor:map.Annotation_GREEN,
    })];

    Map.addAnnotations(Ann);
    // Method to check Location On Device
    // if (e.error) {     
        // alert('HFL cannot get your current location');
        // return;
    // } else {
            /*********For Device***/
            // longitude = clon;
            // latitude = clat;
            /****For Simulator*****/
             latitude=28.5015171, 
             longitude=77.0857142,
    // Assign the destination Latitude and Longitude.
    destinationLongitude = 77.1122;destinationLatitude=28.5686;

    // The bellow URL is used to Get the route of current location to assigned  destination Location. 

    var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" +   latitude+','+longitude + "&destination=" + destinationLatitude +','+ destinationLongitude +"&sensor=true";

    // The Bellow URL use the static current location to destination  Location. 
    // var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?  origin=37.422502,-122.0855498&destination=37.389569,-122.050212&sensor=true";

    var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    Ti.API.info('URL: ' + url);

    xhr.onload = function() {
        Ti.API.info('inside the xhr-->' + this.responseText);
        var xml = this.responseText;
        var points = [];
        // Bellow Variable have the step of the current location to destination  Location.  Using the Steps we going to create a route.
        var position = JSON.parse(this.responseText).routes[0].legs[0].steps;
        if (position[0] != null) {
            points.push({
                latitude : position[0].start_location.lat,
                longitude : position[0].start_location.lng,
            });
            // Here we use the for loop to collect all the steps and push it to the array and use this array to form the route in android.

            for (var i = 0; i < position.length; i++){
                points.push({
                    latitude : position[i].end_location.lat,
                    longitude : position[i].end_location.lng,
                });
            }
        }

        var route=map.addRoute({
            points:points,
            width:4,
            color:'blue'
        });
        Map.add(route);

    };
    // };
    window.open();
    window.add(Map);
});
```

**Error log**

```
[INFO] :   TiRootActivity: (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity resume. activity  = com.and.AndroidmapActivity@417def20
[WARN] :   InputMethodManager: startInputInner : InputBindResult == null
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3896 (MapAttrs) in  Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3886    (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3886 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3881 (common_google_play_services_install_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3877 (common_google_play_services_enable_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3892 (common_google_play_services_update_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3889 (common_google_play_services_unsupported_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3885 (common_google_play_services_network_error_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3886 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3886 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3883 (common_google_play_services_invalid_account_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3886 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3889 (common_google_play_services_unsupported_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3878 (common_google_play_services_install_button) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3875 (common_google_play_services_enable_button) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3890 (common_google_play_services_update_button) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string; 
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3886 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3880 (common_google_play_services_install_text_tablet) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3879 (common_google_play_services_install_text_phone) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3876 (common_google_play_services_enable_text) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3891 (common_google_play_services_update_text) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3888 (common_google_play_services_unsupported_text) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3884 (common_google_play_services_network_error_text) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3882 (common_google_play_services_invalid_account_text) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3887 (common_google_play_services_unsupported_date_text) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3886 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
[ERROR] :  GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
[INFO] :   I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 4132500
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Could not find method gui.a, referenced from method gqh.a
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 24934: Lgui;.a (Landroid/content/Context;)Lgrh;
[ERROR] :  dalvikvm: Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;
[ERROR] :  dalvikvm: Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;
[ERROR] :  dalvikvm: Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;
[INFO] :   I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 5089034
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 20875 (t) in Lyo;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 20875 (t) in Lyo;
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Failed resolving  Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence; interface 4023 'Lglm;'
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;' failed
[ERROR] :  dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method gls.a
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2086 (Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;) in Lgls;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 3896 (MapAttrs) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40dd8258)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: (main) [2486,2486] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.ClassCastException: ti.map.AnnotationProxy cannot be cast to java.lang.Object[]; Titanium 3.3.0,2014/07/11 12:36,787cd39
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: java.lang.ClassCastException: ti.map.AnnotationProxy cannot be cast to java.lang.Object[]
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: at ti.map.TiUIMapView.processMapProperties(TiUIMapView.java:156)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: at ti.map.TiUIMapView.onViewCreated(TiUIMapView.java:111)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: at org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiUIFragment.handleMessage(TiUIFragment.java:65)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[WARN] :   TiVerify: (Timer-0) [2385,4871] Verifying module licenses...
[INFO] :   Process: Sending signal. PID: 31701 SIG: 9
```

Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: There seem to be a java exception (invalid cast). this could be caused by inappropriate data being passed... What i would do is write API.info logs in my js script to see exactly where the line that causes the crash and than take it from there.

Comment: That seems to be a memory error to me . Thanks for your help anyway.I have fixed that now map is running well on android device and simulator